# W10 UWP CompactOverlay button icon

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app

Can't figure out what the Segoe MDL2 icon used for [CompactOverlay (Picture in Picture)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/universal-windows-app-model/2017/02/11/compactoverlay-mode-aka-picture-in-picture/) mode is. See example picture below. Anyone have any ideas?

[image: CompactOverlay button example]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that symbol is in the font, but it can be synthesized by layering two symbols (E7FB and EB9F). Something similar to this:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Margin="10"
                FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                FontSize="15">&#xE7FB;</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Margin="16,12,0,0"
                FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                FontSize="6  ">&#xEB9F;</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks - that was it! I placed it in `AppBarButton.Content` and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

They use different font called "SegMVR2.ttf".
I took it here:

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.ZuneVideo_10.17092.13511.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Resources\Fonts
```

Then, in XAML i used this markup:

```
<AppBarButton>
    <AppBarButton.Icon>
        <FontIcon FontFamily="ms-appx:/Resources/Fonts/SegMVR2.ttf#Segoe MVR MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xF15E;"/>
    </AppBarButton.Icon>
</AppBarButton>
```